# Set "Accept" headers in jQuery for retrieving data in iframe

Tags: jquery, ajax, iframe, header

I have a webpage to which I'm appending an iframe as follows:

```
$('<iframe id="testIframe" />').src('http://www.google.nl/').appendTo('body');
```

The Accept headers sent for loading the content of this iframe are set to:

```
application/xml, application/xml+xhtml, text/html, text/plain, */*
```

Problem here is that the response is now returned as XML because the accept headers are read on the server side and the response is sent back in the format as sent by accept header (in this case using application/xml).

Now I know I could use the $.load() functionality and set the accept headers for that but I wouldn't know how to show the returned HTML in the iframe. For example, this shows a blank iframe:

```
$('#testIframe').load('http://www.google.com/', function(response) {
    $('#testIframe').append(response);
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
$('#testIframe').load('http://www.google.com/', function(response) {
    var doc = $('#testIframe')[0].contentDocument || $('#testIframe')[0].contentWindow.document
    doc.write(response);
    doc.close()
});
```